# Which display server will Ubuntu 13.10 ship?

Tags: release-management

Which display server will Ubuntu 13.10 ship?  Mir, XMir or X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

13.10 will ship with X by default. You will be able to install Mir separately for testing.

XMir isn't a display server, but rather a go-between that allows X to run on top of Mir. This allows backwards compatibility with X-only applications and allows them to run on Mir without (major) modification. If you're using both Mir and the traditional desktop; you'll be using XMir to do it.

<sub>**Source:** https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-October/037695.html</sub>